# How to store activecell.cells properly

Tags: vba, excel

Hi just a quick question.
I need to know how I can effectively store the value of an `ActiveCell`?
I've been trying to:

```
Dim acStore As String
acstore = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 1)
```

But it's not working. I usually get a mismatch error.
I even tried `Dim acstore As Range` but to no avail.
What I want to do is shorten this code:

```
ActiveCell.Cells(1, 5).Copy _
    Destination:=wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

to something like:

```
acStore.Copy Destination:=wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: by the way the longer code works. i just want to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah reviewed your question and the proper way to do it is:

```
Dim acstore As Range
Set acstore = ActiveCell(1, 5)
```

Then you can use the code that you want.

Comment: but i only need a certain cell. not the whole row.

Comment: @SO Yep correct. But as I was editing OP's question, I saw that what OP needs is just pass the object to a variable.

Comment: @L42 Your edit appeared as I pressed the "Add Comment" button - had I seen the edit first I wouldn't have commented :)

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the active cell is a string, then the following will work:

```
acStore$ = ActiveCell.Value
```

If the value is not a string, but you want it to be stored as one, then use:

```
acStore$ = CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
```

Comment: apparently it's not working using L42's method. i'm getting a type mismatch on my next line of code: wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = wsTest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value + " -C"  .. what this does is go to paste the activecell info, like a series of numbers for like an ID number (eg 12456) then add an identifier on the other sheet so the input will be 123456-C. edit: i don't know how to use the tags here to make it portion of my reply as code